# Why image did not show up with Image from react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

My app's splashscreen loads an image from local `asset/image/` subdirectory. I understand that the local image file needs to be `require`. So the image was `require` and assign to a const. The `Image` is `import` from `react-native-elements 2.0.2`:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native-elements';
const bgimage = require('../../../asset/image/ltx-61.jpg');
```

And the function returns:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
      <Image 
        source={bgimage}
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
      />       
    </View>
  );
}
```

But the image was not showing and there was an empty block in place of image. For the test purpose, I tried the following online image which the app successfully loaded and displayed in the app:

```
source={{uri:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg"}}
```

The result is the same. Not image shown and there was a empty block. However if the app import Image from `react-native 0.62.2`:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
```

Then the image loads successfully. Why the image were not showing up with the `Image` from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/image.html)?

Comment: Is the image showing up in the normal image component ?

Comment: The image shows with Image from react-native, but not with Image from react-native-elements.